# Copying files based its name to matching destination folders

Tags: powershell, cmd.exe

I have files like this.

`Makeup_Artists_A_Kreations_Hair_And_Beyond
Makeup_Artists_A_Kreations_Hair_And_Beyond1
Makeup_Artists_A_Kreations_Hair_And_Beyond2
Makeup_Artists_A_Kreations_Hair_And_Beyond3
Makeup_Artists_A_Kreations_Hair_And_Beyond4
Makeup_Artists_A_Kreations_Hair_And_Beyond5
Make_Artist_JustinWorks
Make_Artist_JustinWorks1
Make_Artist_JustinWorks2`

I wanted to move/copy this files to folder named.
`A_Kreations_Hair_And_Beyond` and `JustinWorks`.

Any inputs/ ?

Notes/Tips: I have folder structure ready and `Make Artist` is common in all files. I am tired of trying all the inputs search result in this site.

thanks

Comment: Frankly speaking, I didn't get similar Question on this site. but i found this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609776/copy-files-from-one-folder-to-another-based-on-similar-file-name. but its perl. I am not  much it BATCH, SHELL. I am GIS Guy ;-)

Comment: SuperUser is not a "do my work for me" site and your profile shows some programming knowledge (on StackOverflow). If you tell us what you've tried and where you're stuck we can try to help.

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

Powershell and batch solutions aren't so different.
Past into Powershell/cmd - console

Batch:

```
For %A in ("JustinWorks" "A_Kreations_Hair_And_Beyond"
  ) Do (if not Exist ".\%~A" MD ".\%~A"
    Move ".\*%~A*" ".\%~A\"
)
```

Powershell

```
"JustinWorks", "A_Kreations_Hair_And_Beyond"|
  %{$Name=$_;if (!(Test-Path(".\$_"))) {MD ".\$_"};
    GCI "*$Name*" |%{MV -path "$_" -dest ".\$Name\" -ea silentlycontinue}}
```

**Edit**

A batch file solution assuming the PreFix is constantly `Make_Artist_` The var `BaseFldr`has to be changed accordingly. The command `Move /Y` will overwrite files already present in the subfolder, to be asked change to `Move /-Y`

```
:: move2Sub.cmd :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
@echo off & setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
Set BaseFldr="Q:\Test\2016-11\02"
PushD %BaseFldr% ||(Echo Can't cd to %BaseFldr% & Pause & Goto :eof)
Set "PreFix=Makeup_Artists_"
For /F "delims=" %%A in (
  'Dir /B/ON/A-D "%PreFix%*" ^>Nul 2^>^&1'
    ) Do Call :CheckFile "%%~nxA"
Goto :Eof
:CheckFile "FullName"
If Not Exist %1 Goto :Eof
Set "File=%~n1"
:: remove Prefix
Set "Name=!File:%PreFix%=!"
:: check for trailing number, should already be processed
:Again
Echo:%Name:~-1%|Findstr "[0-9]" >Nul 2>&1 &&(Set "Name=!Name:~0,-1!"&Goto :Again)
If Not Exist "%Name%" MD "%Name%"
Move /Y "%PreFix%%Name%*%~x1" "%Name%" >NUL
Goto :Eof
```

HTH

Comment: How to make variable "JustinWorks"  and "A_Kreations_Hair_And_Beyond" as variable?

Comment: Do you have a list/collection/array of Names to process Which type of script would you use PoSh/batch or any high level language?

Comment: I think it should split by `"Makeup_Artists_"` take the value after this string.`"Makeup_Artists_"` is common pattern in all files names.

Comment: What about `Make_Artist_` and how to treat the trailing numbers? Your question is IMO off topic at this site see [Help Center Asking](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask). Changing the question under way is also a nogo. Neverless I'll refine my answer if I get some time